# Read data from two tables

Tags: android, sqlite, union-all

Consider the tables listed below

**`Table credit`**

```
id    cr_amount  created_date
```

```
1     1000       2011-07-01
2     2000       2011-07-08
3     6000       2011-07-09
```

And `Table debit` entries are follows.

```
id   dr_amount  created_date
```

```
1    3000       2011-07-09
```

**Need to read columns `cr_amount`, `dr_amount` and `created_date` from above tables in ordered by `created date` as shown below.**

```
cr_amount  dr_amount   created_date
```

```
1000        NULL         2011-07-01
2000        NULL         2011-07-08
6000        NULL         2011-07-22
NULL        3000         2011-07-09
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to put both columns in the union all:

```
select cr_amount,Null as 'db_amount',created from table_credit
union all
select Null,db_amount,created from table_debit
order by created
```

Comment: You're welcome; if this worked for you, please accept the answer.